# Declaring a variable in the if condition for further testing in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, shorthand

I've seen it done before in a c# tutorial but I can't seem to find it again.

Take this code for example:

```
public class Order
{
    public  OrderItem Item { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public void SomeMethod(object obj)
{
    if(obj is Order && ((Order)obj).Item !=null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((Order)obj).Item.Name);
    }
}
```

The shorthand I'm looking for looks something like this

```
public void SomeMethod(object obj)
{
    if (myObj = obj is Order && myItem = myObj.Item != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myItem.Name);
    }
}
```

I'm not able to find the correct syntax for that

Comment: `obj is Order myObj`

Comment: Fleshing out @HansKeﬆing's answer: `if (obj is Order myObj  && myObj.Item != null)`

Comment: This needs pattern matching, a recent feature. It's not shorthand. `if(obj is Order myObjd && myObj.Item is Whatever myItem){....}`. Or you can use the null-safe operator `if (obj?.Item is Whatever myItem){...}`

Comment: Thank you all for your input, @HansKeﬆing 's solution is exactly what I was looking for. Could you please post it as an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching).

With property patterns (C# 8.0) you can do something like this:

```
if (obj is Order { Item: { } } order)
{
    Console.WriteLine(order.Item.Name);
}
```

This will check that `obj` is an `Order` and it has non-null `Item` (via ["empty" property pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/#property-patterns)) and if both result in true will execute the code block using typed variable `order`.

Or even next:

```
if (obj is Order { Item: { } item })
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Basically the same but will use `item` variable for non-null item.

Comment: That looks horrible :D So the `Item: { }` denotes that item shouldn't be null? That will take some getting used to. From a quick look, it doesn't look very readable... I'll upvote, but from the example given in the OP, the comments under the OP seem to give the version that the user is after. Which language version is your answer, C# 9?

Comment: @Icepickle yes this is an [empty property pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/#property-patterns) which is basically null check

Comment: @Icepickle this should work from C# 8.0.